# Facebook graph post on feed is not visible in newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an application that posts specific information on a user's wall. This message should also be visible in the newsfeed, but this part is where it goes wrong.

I 'post' following information to the feed graph:

```
<?php 
array(
  'link' => string 'https://www.facebook.com/page' ,
  'picture' => string 'http://...../picture.png' ,
  'name' => string 'Name' ,

  'caption' => string 'caption' ,
  'description' => string 'info text' ,
  'message' => string 'message' 
)
?>
```

(All the information is filled in with usefull information, but for this question I made it quicker readable).

The information comes on the user's wall, but not in the news feed. This happens also from the user's side of the story: He can see the post on his wall, but not in any feed. Also when we try with other friends.

I also tried to only post a message (without link and picture), but it still is not visible in the general newsfeed.

The auth permissions are set and available (publish_stream) and the permissions are also correct when I look at them on the wall. I use the same code as an older app. Maybe it is a setting on the developer page? Sandbox mode is off...

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: We are testing this post-on-wall function and saw an entry in the newsfeed. After refreshing the page, the entry isn't in the news feed anymore. Maybe a facebook-bug?

Or do we have to 'activate' the app somewhere?

Comment: Some extra info: We always use the same message, with 3 variables:
%name has thrown an %object in your %bodyparty. The message is always more or less the same. We also use the same link every post. The image depends on the %object parameter. Can this be an issue?
Maybe the link or the image is the issue?

Comment: Possible related info:
I just checked out the insights page of the app. When I look at the likes / story, this had a poor rating (because we were just testing). This rate is 0.008 and we get the message: 'This app is in the bottom 15th percentile of likes / story compared to apps of similar size'. Propably our story doesn't appear on the recent feeds part, because of a bad rating. Is this correct, or does Facebook doesnt care about this rating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be releated to the fact you're sending a link, apparently FB doesn't like this anymore :

"

Updating a User's Status

You can use this method to simply update a user's status. When you do so, the status message appears at the top of the user's profile and on the Friends > Status Updates page. The message also appears in the stream with your application icon.

To use this method to set a user's status do the following:

```
* Do not include an attachment or action link. If you do, the story will get published and will appear in the stream and on the user's Wall only. It won't appear at the top of the profile or in the Status Updates page.
* Make sure the message is no longer than 420 characters. Otherwise, an error gets returned.
```

"

as per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/streamPublish/

Comment: That must be the reason. Very strange, becaust I still see automatic posts with attachments from other applications. Very sad that this isn't possible anymore. Lot's of campaigns are based on this principle. I guess they want companies to create ads instead of creating their own - fun - applications.

Answer (score 1):

What Facebook chooses to display on the newfeed is done via algorithm.  There are options each user can set to view items in the news feed.  Recent Stories first and Popular stories first.  If the popular is selected, then facebook algorithms kick into overdrive.  If recent stories, then it should display all available stream items (based on other privacy settings) into the feed.

Comment: I have tested this and we both have recent stories. The post is shown, but a few minutes later it is removed from the recent stories view. Is there a limit on posting to news feeds or something? At the moment we have posted like 20 feed posts in 3 days, which is not much ...

Comment: I doubt that 20 feed posts in 3 days would get your app banned.  Unless those posts were deemed by facebook to be something out of the ordinary with enough people marking those as spam, then facebook might stop showing them.  I honestly don't know Facebook's algorithms and getting anyone from Facebook to share that with us is impossible (as it is propietary information).

Comment: I doubt it ... It just in a testing fase with some friends before we do a mailing about the app.

Answer (score 0):

Read this if your still wondering why auto posts and api feeds are not showing on the main news feed to others! Facebook dont like us saving our time they want us to sit on there site and supply quality posts and not focus on our own website!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

Comment: I also have found out that links only get any weight with facebook if you pay for the post to be in the news feed! Its all about the money with facebook